# Send a broadcast notification with string (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to send a notification between two class. 
In Android I have used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_KEY);
intent.putExtra(ISFIRSTTIME, isfirsttime);     
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance
(AppDelegate.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and to recive:

```
private BroadcastReceiver multiselectReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
};
```

And in IOS:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter 
defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kNotificationMultiselectController 
object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isFirstTime]];
```

and to recive:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(multiselectNotification:) 
name:kNotificationMultiselectController object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for loosely coupled messaging in C#, none UWP-specific. If you build your app using a MVVM framework, it will likely contain one as well - for example Prism has `EventAggregator`, MvvmCross has `MvxMessenger` and in MvvmLight you use `MessengerDefault`. I would choose one of the frameworks and use the provided messenger capability as it is battle tested and stable. You don't even have to use the full MVVM framework itself and just utilize the event aggregator component. For more info on how it works see for example [this MSDN blogpost](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx).

The most basic solution would be to use basic C# events, but those are strong references, meaning you need to remember to unsubscribe from the events you have registered otherwise the subscriber will stay in memory.